# Web Api 2.0 Routing - multiple actions matching

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have this WebAPI controller, having 2 methods. This controller is more of a utility type controller, and not really focusing on one type of entity, like most examples and boiler-plate template will generate. Anyway, my 2 methods are something like this:

```
    // api/Custom/SayHello
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> SayHello()
    {

        return await Task.FromResult("Hello World Async").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    // api/Custom/SayFloat
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<float> SayFloat()
    {

        return await Task.FromResult(1000.0f).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

And I've gone through a lot of routing template combinations, and my latest one is this:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", 
            "Api/{controller}/{id}", 
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        /* ----- this is trying to match my utility controller and its actions ----- */
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
```

I'm getting this error: Multiple actions were found that match the request ....

So my current "workaround", is to create one controller, per utility method that I want to expose. I'm thinking that there's gotta be something that I haven't tried with the routing template. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer to this question is correct.  However, I wanted to offer an alternative which I am a fan of, [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

> The first release of Web API used convention-based routing. In that type of routing, you define one or more route templates, which are basically parameterized strings. When the framework receives a request, it matches the URI against the route template.

With Attribute Routing, on the other hand, you decorate your Controllers and Actions with Attributes which allows for a much more flexible routing scheme.

```
[Route("api/custom")]
public class CustomController : ApiController
...
// api/Custom/SayHello
[Route("SayHello")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> SayHello()
{
    return await Task.FromResult("Hello World Async").ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// api/Custom/SayFloat
[Route("SayFloat")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<float> SayFloat()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(1000.0f).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: I agree, Attribute Routing is the better way to go if you are using WebApi2.

Answer (score 1):

Web API will match the routes in the order it finds them, so you need to change the order of your routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{action}"
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routetemplate "Api/{controller}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

A word of warning though, this will stop the defaultapi route working with an id parameter. I might be better to declare your controller explicitly:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "Api/Custom/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Custom" }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routetemplate "Api/{controller}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```